# I get python errors with installing pre-requisites onto a node.js project

Tags: python, node.js, prerequisites

I am installing all the packages needed in a node.js project I downloaded and I am getting a ton of errors that I have no idea how to resolve them. It seems to be involved with getting python to run. I have both 2.7 and 3.3 on my computer.

Here are some images of the errors

[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Python 2.7 is either not on your `PATH` or else is after Python 3.3. You can solve this problem by either:

- Passing the path to Python 2.7 using the `--python` flag (as it states in the error) *or*
- By adding the path to Python 2.7 (C:\Python27, most likely) to your `PATH` (or by moving it before C:\Python33 in the list).

Answer (score 1):

> You can pass the `--python` switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0

Did you try that?

The problem here is that apparently to build that module, Python 2 is required, but your standard Python executable in the PATH is the Python 3 executable.

Other than that, it might be a good idea to ask the module maintainer to upgrade his build process to support Python 3 too.

Comment: Okay I got it to compile I think, but now I get a crazy amount of errors and warnings. Here is a quick video of it: http://screencast.com/t/svgMjkISJX

Comment: `--python=python2` 
npm is made by naughty people.

Answer (score 0):

if python2 is in your path (applies to a lot of linux setups)
`npm install node-gyp-package --python=python2`